# Vuetify - Passing props to the tag created by router-link

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js, vue-router

When using `tag` to override the tag used to create the link, how can I pass props to the created Vue component?

Here you can see that I am using a `v-list-item` tag inside of a `v-list` (not shown). This works as expected and the `v-list-item` is parsed by Vue as a Vuetify component. However, I can't figure out how to pass props to the `v-list-item`

```
<router-link
    :to="{name: 'home'}"
    tag="v-list-item"
>
  <v-list-item-action>
    <v-icon>mdi-home</v-icon>
  </v-list-item-action>
  <v-list-item-content>
    <v-list-item-title>
      Home
    </v-list-item-title>
  </v-list-item-content>
</router-link>
```

I've tried

```
<router-link
    :to="{name: 'home'}"
    tag="v-list-item"
    :disabled="isDisabled"
>
```

...but it doesn't work.

Comment: did you try out my answer?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim Yes. I upvoted at the time, but it wouldn't allow we to accept it yet. I'll do so now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use directly the `v-list-item` and add `to` prop to it by passing the path name :

```
<v-list-item     :to="{name: 'home'}">
```

in the [official API](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/lists/) select `v-list-item` from the drop down and go to the `to` prop with description :

> Denotes the target route of the link. You can find more information about the to prop on the vue-router documentation.